# Custom validator throws exception javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-validator

I want to force user to send numeric value for a field in request, as user may enter char as well.
Since I haven't found any built in solution in spring mvc validation, I chose to create my own custom validator to check the entered value is number or not. 
Please find below code snippet.

Constraint interface :

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy =  {IntegerValidator.class})
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface IntegerConstraint {
    String message() default "Please enter numers only...!!!";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Validator class :

```
public class IntegerValidator implements ConstraintValidator<IntegerConstraint, String> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(IntegerConstraint contactNumber) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String reqParam, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        return !StringUtils.isEmpty(reqParam) && reqParam.matches("^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$");
    }
}
```

DTO class field :

```
@IntegerConstraint
@PositiveOrZero(message = "Sorting number either can be positive or zero...!!!")
private Integer sortOrd;
```

Controller :

```
public ModelAndView addDetail(@Valid @ModelAttribute("fooDetails") FooDTO footDTO,
            BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request)
```

Error log :

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'com.eps.customvalidator.IntegerConstraint' validating type 'java.lang.Integer'. Check configuration for 'sortOrd'
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getExceptionForNullValidator(ConstraintTree.java:108) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.10.Final.jar:6.0.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.getInitializedConstraintValidator(ConstraintTree.java:140) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.10.Final.jar:6.0.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.SimpleConstraintTree.validateConstraints(SimpleConstraintTree.java:55) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.10.Final.jar:6.0.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:73) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.10.Final.jar:6.0.10.Final]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might happened because your `IntegerValidator` is implementing `ConstraintValidator<IntegerConstraint, String>`, thus it is expected to validate String fields. But you are applying it on an Integer field.

You should either consider to change `ConstraintValidator<IntegerConstraint, String>` to `ConstraintValidator<IntegerConstraint, Integer>` or to change your DTO to `private String sortOrd;`